# Ajax calls php file insert data in MySQL, want to see php errors

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using jquery. With an Ajax call I execute a php script to insert data in a MySQL database. Everythings works fine on php7. Now i'm checking my code on php8 and get an error from error: function().

An error occurs somewhere when executing insert.php. Been trying for a while to display the error from the error function with alert(data);

But can't figure out how to do this. I really just want to see all output just like if I execute the insert.php directly.

Can anyone help me? How can I use 'echo json_encode' to send all display output (errors) back?

```
   $.ajax({
    url : (typeof id === 'undefined'? 'pages/insert.php' : 'pages/update.php'),   //Afhankelijk of er al is opgeslagen bij het printen kiezen tussen insert of update
    method:'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    data:{
        publish:publish,
        id:id,                                                                                                                                          // bij insert wordt niets met id gedaan
        fromDateTime:fromDateTime,
        toDateTime:toDateTime,
        kind:kind,
        locationId:locationId,
        title:title.trim(),
        content:content.trim(),
        mediaArray:mediaArray
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('Insert error!');
        alert(data);
    },
    success:function(data){
        id=data.id;
        window.location.href = "index.php";
    }
  });
```

PHP-file

```
<?php
 session_start();

 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);

 // Connect database
 include '../../conndb.php';

 if ($_POST['publish']==="true"){
    $activeWebsite = 1;
 }
 else {
    $activeWebsite = 0;
 }

 $user = $_SESSION['id'];
 $fromDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['fromDateTime']));
 $toDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['toDateTime']));
 $kind = $_POST['kind'];
 $locationId = $_POST['locationId'];
 $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['title']);
 $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['content']);
 $content = preg_replace('/^(<br\s*?\/?>)+|(<br\s*\/?>)+$/', '', $content);
 $mediaArray = $_POST['mediaArray'];
 $createDateTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

 $actie = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO Cont (User_id, SoortBericht, Teaser, Plaats_id, VanDatum, TotDatum, OpmaakDatum, Bericht, Act_internet, Views) VALUES ('$user', '$kind', '$title', '$locationId', '$fromDateTime', '$toDateTime', '$createDateTime', '$content', '$activeWebsite', 0);") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

 $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
 echo json_encode(['id'=>$last_id]);
 $id = $last_id;

?>
```

Comment: Just use your browser's network tool - open it, run your code, look for the ajax request, click on it then view the Response tab. Also...get php to log errors to a file instead of putting them in the output, then you always know where to look

Comment: you won't get php errors in your browser by default - check your server logs. however, you might be interested in including https://github.com/maximebf/php-debugbar which will add log information from php in your browser, which can be very handy
also note - your code as it stands is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: Use prepared statements and parameterized queries. Stop using `mysqli_real_escape_string`. You aren't even using it on all values which makes any use of it worthless.

Answer (score -1):

As a general solution, you can wrap your entire server code in a `try/catch` block. Decide on some sort of protocol for responses `['result' => ..., 'error' => ...]` then output the response as a `result` or as `error`. Since it's PHP you might need to configure some stuff so you catch most if not all errors.

```php
<?php

try {
    $last_id = insert_something();

    echo json_encode([
        'result' => [
            'id' => $last_id
        ]
    ]);

} catch (Exception $e) {

    // you can log to server
    error_log((string) $e);

    echo json_encode([
        'error' => [
            'msg' => $e->getMessage()
        ]
    ]);
}
```

Back on client, expect to handle the `data.error` or the `data.result` in the `success(data)` callback.

There is always possibility to get other errors in your AJAX, so you still need to handle those gracefully, but the real information of the error is, indeed, in the server logs.

Comment: This effectively hides the error and streams it into the client/server protocol. This will only enlarge the problem.

Comment: There are many ways to handle errors, logging and notifications on server. I have provided just a simple approach answering the OP question 'how to send the error to client  using json_encode?'

Comment: Yes, sure, there are really _many_ ways, and thinking: what does constitute an error in the first place? Hard to answer, right? Therefore, define errors out of existence. One anti-pattern there  is to log exceptions, this populates many generations if errors. We can see it in the answers' example and is one of the reasons why I DV-ed it (what I normally don't do often, hopefully the takeaway pleases yourself first of all, only.) YMMV; _"A program that produces incorrect results twice as fast is infinitely slower." — John Osterhout_

Comment: But when I only for debugging want to see whats errors the insert.php gives, how can I display the output on the screen? Actually, I just want to see what happens if I were to access the page directly from the browser. 

I did manage this before, but don't remember how. Somehow I got the output in the alert function.

Comment: you did manage with your code? maybe jquery ajax error handler expects `function (request, status, error) { alert(request.responseText) }`

Comment: Yes, with code. All html output (errors) from the insert.php I send back and show it with an alert (only for debuging). But I can't remember me how I did it...